# Wordpress PHP back to search results

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a 'Back To Search Results' link in order to go back to the previous page.

Basically you can perform a search, and afterwards go into a single-post page. In this page I'd like to create the link.

I tried : 
        `<?php
  $url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  echo "<a href='$url'>back</a>"; 
?>`

But it only send you back to the previous page (let's say someone got to the website from google...then it would take him back to google I suppose.)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with a link like this (that's different for every person) is that you're going to lose the ability to do full-page caching with something like W3 Total Cache or WP Super Cache. If performance/scaling is a concern for your site, you should probably consider how important this link is or build your solution with that in mind.

Comment: Why not? I just need to store somehow the url, and then echo it on the single post page no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I managed to do it with a `$_SESSION` variable:

On the page that loads after clicking search (usually archive.php or similar) I added this code before the footer:

```
            <?php 
            if (isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) { 
            $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
            } 
            ?>
```

Then, I added to the single page the code bellow:

```
<div class="back-to-search">
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['url'])) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $_SESSION['url']; ?>">Back To Search</a>
    <?php else: ?>    
        <a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>">Back To Search</a>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

So basically if the `$_SESSION` is set from the search results, it takes you back to the results. If not (for example if you arrived directly from google etc.) The link will redirect to the homepage (where all the listings appear by default)

Comment: You may want to unset the session variable after you've used it, otherwise it   will still be set if the user browses back to the single-post page from a different referrer.

Answer (score 0):

'HTTP_REFERER'
The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

So you should think of another way to re-create the URL. Try to send the URL as a POST variable with the Search you are performing. Then you can simply read it from `$_POST`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I use the `$_POST` variable if it's on two different pages? (The page with the search results should be stored, but the single page should have the link)